# combining Json and normal columns with Pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a flatfile that mixes normal columns with Json columns

```
2020-08-05 00:00:04,489|{"Colour":"Blue", "Reason":"Sky","number":"1"}
2020-10-05 00:00:04,489|{"Colour":"Yellow", "Reason":"Flower","number":"2"}
```

I want to flatten it out like this using pyspark:

```
|Timestamp|Colour|Reason|
|--------|--------|--------|
|2020-08-05 00:00:04,489|Blue| Sky|
|2020-10-05 00:00:04,489|Yellow| Flower|
```

At the moment I can only figure out how to convert the Json by using spark.read.json and Map but how do you combine regular columns like the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Lets reconstruct your data

```
data2 = [("2020-08-05 00:00:04,489",'{"Colour":"Blue", "Reason":"Sky","number":"1"}'),
    ("2020-10-05 00:00:04,489",'{"Colour":"Yellow", "Reason":"Flower","number":"2"}')]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("x",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("y",StringType(),True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

As per documentation we can use `schema_of_json` to parses a JSON string and infers its schema in DDL format

```
schema=df.select(F.schema_of_json(df.select("y").first()[0])).first()[0]

df.withColumn("y", F.from_json("y",\ schema)).selectExpr('x',"y.*").show(truncate=False)

+-----------------------+------+------+------+
|x                      |Colour|Reason|number|
+-----------------------+------+------+------+
|2020-08-05 00:00:04,489|Blue  |Sky   |1     |
|2020-10-05 00:00:04,489|Yellow|Flower|2     |
+-----------------------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_json_object`. Assuming that the original columns are called `col1` and `col2`, then you can do:

```
df2 = df.select(
    F.col('col1').alias('Timestamp'), 
    F.get_json_object('col2', '$.Colour').alias('Colour'), 
    F.get_json_object('col2', '$.Reason').alias('Reason')
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------+------+------+
|Timestamp              |Colour|Reason|
+-----------------------+------+------+
|2020-08-05 00:00:04,489|Blue  |Sky   |
|2020-10-05 00:00:04,489|Yellow|Flower|
+-----------------------+------+------+
```

Or you can use `from_json`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select(
    F.col('col1').alias('Timestamp'), 
    F.from_json('col2', 'Colour string, Reason string').alias('col2')
).select('Timestamp', 'col2.*')

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------+------+------+
|Timestamp              |Colour|Reason|
+-----------------------+------+------+
|2020-08-05 00:00:04,489|Blue  |Sky   |
|2020-10-05 00:00:04,489|Yellow|Flower|
+-----------------------+------+------+
```